# Parse XML subtags with same name in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

i am new to swift. I have created an XML parser that reads each tag (tag and subtag) one by one. The problem that I found is that there are some subtags with the same name, so my code can't differentiate. I need to know how to read a concrete subtag to differentiate and store it in different variables.

This is the XML (reduced) that I am parsing:

```
<_0:situationRecord id="GUID_Suc_3971318_3971318" xsi:type="_0:NetworkManagement">
    <_0:identifier>171826</_0:identifier>
    <_0:to xsi:type="_0:TPEGNonJunctionPoint">
        <_0:name>
            <_0:descriptor>
                <_0:value>MADRID</_0:value>
            </_0:descriptor>
            <_0:tpegDescriptorType>other</_0:tpegDescriptorType>
        </_0:name>
    </_0:to>
    <_0:from xsi:type="_0:TPEGNonJunctionPoint">
        <_0:name>
            <_0:descriptor>
                <_0:value>SANTIAGO DE COMPOSTELA</_0:value>
            </_0:descriptor>
            <_0:tpegDescriptorType>other</_0:tpegDescriptorType>
        </_0:name>
    </_0:from>
</_0:situationRecord>
```

This is my ParseINCDGT.swift class:

```
import Foundation

struct INCIDENCIADGT {
    var identifier: String
    var valueFrom: String
    var valueTo: String
}

class ParseINCDGT: NSObject, XMLParserDelegate {
    private var myData: Data
    private var currentElementName = ""
    private var inItem = false
    private var item: INCIDENCIADGT
    var ready = false
    
    var auxLat = 1
    var auxLong = 1
    var aux = 1
    
    var items: [INCIDENCIADGT]
    
    override init() {
        //Default values
        myData = "".data(using: .ascii)!
        items = []
        item = INCIDENCIADGT(identifier: "", valueFrom: "", valueTo: "")
    }
    
    // Set the local data set for parsing
    func setData(data: Data) -> Void {
        if data == nil {
            return
        }
        myData = data
    }
    
    // Runs the parsing process, returns at the end. Please note that this function is synchronous, while internally asynchronous
    func parse() -> Void {
        let parser = XMLParser(data: myData)
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse()
    }
    
    // Terminate session
    func parserDidEndDocument(_ parser: XMLParser) {
        ready = true
    }
    
    // Start session
    func parserDidStartDocument(_ parser: XMLParser) {
        ready = false
    }
    
    // Terminate an element
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        currentElementName = elementName
        if elementName == "_0:situationRecord" {
            inItem = false
            items.append(item)
        }
    }
    
    // Starts an element
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
        currentElementName = elementName
        if elementName == "_0:situationRecord" {
            inItem = true
            item = INCIDENCIADGT(identifier: "", valueFrom: "", valueTo: "")
        }
    }
    
    // Collects other data
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        
        switch currentElementName{
        case "_0:identifier":
            item.identifier += string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
        case "_0:value":
            item.valueFrom += string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my method that calls the ParserINCDGT.swift:

```
func loadData() -> Void {
    let url = "http://infocar.dgt.es/datex2/dgt/SituationPublication/all/content.xml"
    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
        
    let session3 = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request3) {
        (data, _, error) in
        
        //Handle errors
        if error != nil {
            //Show error message
            return
        }
        
        guard let data = data else{
            //Data error, show message
            return
        }
        
        //Convert data to string
        var s: String = String(data: data, encoding: .ascii)!
        
        //Make XML conforming to all standards: Convert LF to CR
        s = s.replacingOccurrences(of: "\r", with: "\n")
        
        //Parse XML
        let p = ParseINCDGT()
        p.setData(data: data)
        p.parse()
        
        //Elaborate data
        print(p.items)
        
        if (p.items.count != 0) {
            for item in p.items {
                print(item.identifier)
                print(item.valueFrom)
            }
        }
    }
    //Run!
    session.resume()
}
```

Finally the output for the variable "valueForm" is "MADRIDSANTIAGO DE COMPOSTELA"

Can anyone help me explaining what should I include to parse and differentiate the subtags "_0:value"?

Thank you so much. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to keep track of what the parent tags are, this is how XML is designed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. And can you give me a small example? I am new to swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to add some few changes:

Check if a tag `_0:from` or `_0:to` is started and have it saved in a variable, I called it `isFrom` here, you need to add it to your class (private would be better). And when you look for the text in `_0:value` you add it to the right element of your INCIDENCIADGT struct.

Herer you see the two functions that need change with what needs to be added:

```
// Starts an element
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
    currentElementName = elementName
    if elementName == "_0:situationRecord" {
        inItem = true
        item = INCIDENCIADGT(identifier: "", valueFrom: "", valueTo: "")
    } else if elementName == "_0:from" { // check if we will be looking at from information when getting the next _0:value
        isFrom = true // could use an enum if more posibilities exist than from and to.
    } else if elementName == "_0:to" { // check if getting to information like above
        isFrom = false // could use an enum if more posibilities exist than from and to.
    }
}

// Collects other data
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    
    switch currentElementName{
    case "_0:identifier":
        item.identifier += string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    case "_0:value":
        if isFrom { // write the information in the right field of the struct
            item.valueFrom += string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
        } else {
            item.valueTo += string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
        }
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

There might still be some errors and warning in what I wrote, since I only made it here inside the editor and did not test it in xcode, but if it does not work, it at least gives you an idea of how to start to solve your specific problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. After having been adapting it to my code over the weekend, it works great.